# Unable to convert str to float when reading contents of a file (Python)

Tags: python, literals

My code:

```
myFile = open('Numbers.txt', 'r')

counter = 0
total = 0

num = myFile.read()

while num != '':
    counter += 1
    num = num.rstrip('\n')
    n = float(num)

    total += n
    num = myFile.read()

myFile.close()

print 'Total sum: ' , total
print 'Num of random numbers: ', counter
```

I get: `ValueError: invalid literal for float()`
here: `n = float(num)`

Comment: Have you tried printing `num` to see what it contains?

Comment: There might be non-printing characters. try `print repr(temp)`

Comment: Are You trying to read numbers located in different lines? Try using `readlines` instead of `read` and loop through lines.

Comment: Replace `myFile.read()` with `myFile.readline()`. Refer to my anser for the detailed descriptions.

Comment: what does `Numbers.txt` look like?

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, there is something in the string blocking the float conversion. As a general debugging hint, catch the error to see what is causing the problem

```
try:
    n = float(num)
except ValueError:
    print(repr(temp))
```

it might also help to rewrite

```
with open('Numbers.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    total = 0

    for counter, line in enumerate(myFile):
        num = line.rstrip('\n')
        try:
            n = float(num)
        except ValueError:
            print(repr(temp))
        total += n
```

Answer (score 0):

[`f.read(size)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. Note that when `size` is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned.

For instance, the content of your file is,

```
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

which returns,

```
'3.0\n4.0\n5.0'
```

As you can see, the string is invalid literal for `float()`.

---

To meet your goal, replace `myFile.read()` with `myFile.readline()`. Or do it more pythonic way,

```
counter = 0
total = 0

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        counter += 1
        num = float(line.strip())
        total += num

print(counter, total)
# (3, 12.0)
```

Comment: No need for `.strip()`